# Open a panel below two other panels

Tags: interface

In the following screenshot, I want the panel which the yellow creature is showed in, to be completely below the other two panels (i.e dope sheet and 3d viewport). It's currently below the 3d view. How can I stretch it to be below of both other panels?

[image]

Comment: Split the _Graph Editor_ to the same height as the mini _3D Viewport_ and collapse the mini _3D Viewport_ onto the mini _Graph Editor_.

Comment: @ShadyPuck Thanks it worked! Please write it as an answer, I'll then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the three hash marks at the bottom, left-hand corner of the *Dope Sheet* and drag up to split it. Make sure that the seam between the two *Dope Sheets* is at the same height as the seam between the two *3D Viewports*. Adjust the *3D Viewport's* seam to equalize. If the seams are at the same height, you should be able to grab the three hash marks in the top, right-hand corner of the bottom *3D Viewport*, drag them to the right, and release to collapse the bottom *Dope Sheet*.